# Insert without creating object and only on primary key

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I am having a entity Coupons which contains ManyToOne relation to Packs table.
So when i want to perform insertion on Coupons,i first execute a select query based on id to get a Pack object and then use the query result in my actual Coupon insertion query.
How to insert in Coupons table directly based on id, as ManyToOne relation just makes a new column with foreign key constraint to pack id.

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
repos.productCouponsRepository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .values([{ coupon_code: code,  product_pack: <Some product_pack object> }])
  .execute();
```

I want something like this:

```
repos.productCouponsRepository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .values([{ coupon_code: code, product_pack: <Some product_pack id> }])
  .execute();
```

Entites

```
export class ProductPacks {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToMany(type => ProductCoupons, productCoupon => productCoupon.product_pack,{ onDelete: "CASCADE" })
  product_coupons: ProductCoupons[];
}

export class ProductCoupons {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(type => ProductPacks, productPack => productPack.product_coupons, { onDelete: "CASCADE", nullable: false })
  product_pack: ProductPacks;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code describing the entities `ProductCoupon` and `ProductPack` .

Comment: @noam Added Entites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a relation id column with foreign key to the ProductPacks table.
Add the column `product_pack_id` to the Entity `ProductCoupons`

```
export class ProductCoupons {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @RelationId()
  product_pack_id: number;

  @ManyToOne(type => ProductPacks, productPack => productPack.product_coupons, { onDelete: "CASCADE", nullable: false })
  product_pack: ProductPacks;
}
```

Then insert the `<Some product_pack id>` to `product_pack_id` column

```
repos.productCouponsRepository
.createQueryBuilder()
.insert()
.values([{ coupon_code: code, product_pack_id: <Some product_pack id> }])
.execute();
```

Comment: I edited the answer due to the edit you did in your question.